# Design Time Error - 'VisualState' occurs in at least two namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am getting the following error

*Ambiguous type reference. A type named 'VisualState' occurs in at least two namespaces, 'System.Windows' and 'System.Windows'. Consider adjusting the assembly XmlnsDefinition attributes.*

I am not referencing any of these assembly name spaces directly, I am doing the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

The application compiles fine, just throwing these errors at design time.  This happens to a few other classes that are a part of the VSM library.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to use the WpfToolkit compiled for WPF3.5 with WPF4.  The `VisualStateManager` is now part of WPF4, so if you are using the toolkit for the `DataGrid` or `VisualStateManager`, you can simply remove the toolkit reference to resolve the ambiguity.  If you want to use the toolkit for charting, then you should be using the WPF4 version of charting:

- [Silverlight/WPF Data Visualization Development Release 4](http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9999344)

If you still need to use the old Toolkit with WPF4, you'll have to find all the XAML references to the VisualStateManager and related classes and prefix them with a namespace targeting the specific assembly that contains the `System.Windows.VisualStateManager` you want to use in order to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: I have included the toolkit in my project and am using .NET 4, so this might just be the case.  I'll have to check and see if there was anything from the toolkit I was using that hasn't made it into the framework yet.

Comment: this happened to me when migrating fromm VS 2008 to 2010

Comment: I've just pushed a NuGet package for WPF4 : https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit/

Comment: I replaced the WPF Toolkit for 3.5 with your package, but now I am getting some issues because I am not sure how to add it to the XAML page. (Sorry, WPF newbie here.)

Comment: I eliminated the ambiguity by WPF Toolkit and adding the tools from the link above. My XAML forms are not recognizing the existence of classes within referenced namespaces.
I can get them to come up on intellisense but the application won't compile and the error says "The name "MainWindow" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:FieldSheetPrinter".
I am going to open a new question because this is veering from the original topic, but I wanted to add that the first part was solved by the answer Mr. Sladkey was kind enough to post.