# x:Static in XAML Style attribute leads to ambiguous type reference on 'System.Windows.Markup'

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Adding a special style into XAML form as simple as this (I stripped down all unnecessary tags)

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="MainWin" Title="Main" Height="228" Width="525" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonClose" Content="r" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="491,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Click="ButtonClose_Click" IsCancel="True" BorderThickness="0" Background="#00DDDDDD" Foreground="#FFEEEEEE" FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="16" ToolTip="Close (Esc)"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

is throwing non-blocking error:

> **Ambiguous type reference. A type named 'StaticExtension' occurs in at least two namespaces, 'System.Windows.Markup' and 'System.Windows.Markup'.**

The problem is in attribute `Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"`. If I remove the attribute, the error is gone. Also the problem is gone is I switch the project to .NET 4.

I understand there is a conflict of namespaces as shown in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949651/ambiguous-type-reference-a-type-named-visualstate-occurs-in-at-least-two-name). But how exactly the XAML can be modified to prevent this?

- All the code leading to the error was created by work in designer, not by hand.
- .NET 3.5  (important)
- VS 2012 Update 4
- I'm **not** using ReSharper (as I found in some SO answers, it has known defect regarding this)
- something similar [was reported to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/778210/ambiguous-type-reference-with-x-type-x-static), but for VS 2012 **Update 2**
- **steps to reproduce:** create new project • in wizard choose .NET 3.5, then "WPF Application" • designer opens • paste the XAML • rebuild all • the error is shown

Comment: above code does not reproduce the mentioned error.

Comment: @pushpraj - for me it does.  I have added *steps to reproduce* at the bottom of the question. I have successfujlly tested them right now. In which VS and .NET version did you try that?

Comment: I am using VS2013 with .net 4.5, perhaps that is the reason. let me try if I can find VS2012 somewhere.

Comment: @pushpraj - first, simply start the project in .NET 3.5 (it can be selected in the wizard), maybe you will see the problem in VS2013 as well

Comment: nope, not reproducible in VS2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I'm concluding this that it is a specific problem occurring in configuration
`VisualStudio 2012` + `.NET 3.5` + `WPF`.

It is not a blocking problem, so I can live with it.

__

<sup>(If some has better asnwer, feel free to post it and I'll pottentially mark it as the accepted answer instead of this one.)</sup>